# How can I convert a AVL tree to splay tree?

Tags: data-structures, tree, binary-tree

I've got a generic c++ AVL tree and I'd like to know if it's possible (and not too complicated) to convert my AVL into a Splay tree or is it more efficient to program a Splay tree from zero

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as a "splay tree", in the sense that the splay algorithm does not depend on any additional metadata nor does it impose any constraint on the tree structure. Any arbitrary binary tree can be used with the splay algorithm.

So you can "convert" an AVL tree simply by dropping or ignoring the AVL-specific per-node metadata.